# Java get child method from parent class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a few java classes that extend a parent class. From the parent class, I'm looking to call a couple methods from the child class. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks

Example.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class LookupBaseEntity {

    private List<VehicleConfiguration> vehicleConfigurations;

    public VehicleConfiguration getVehicleConfiguration() {
        return vehicleConfiguration;
    }

    public void setVehicleConfigurations(List<VehicleConfiguration> vehicleConfigurations) {
        this.vehicleConfigurations = vehicleConfigurations;
    }

}
```

child class

```
@Entity
public class VehicleYear extends LookupBaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicleYear")
    private List<VehicleConfiguration> vehicleConfigurations;

    public VehicleYear() {
    }

    public List<VehicleConfiguration> getVehicleConfigurations() {
        return vehicleConfigurations;
    } 

    public void setVehicleConfigurations(List<VehicleConfiguration> vehicleConfigurations) {
        this.vehicleConfigurations = vehicleConfigurations;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Why are you overriding the parent class methods but reusing the same implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would never have a parent directly call a child's methods as the parent should have no knowledge or dependence on the child. The parent can *indirectly* call a child's methods through Java's OOPS ability to override methods of course. In other words, if a parent calls one of its own non-final non-static methods, it will call the method of the current child type via the magic of look-up tables that allow for virtual method calls in Java.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to add a method in the parent class checking whether or not the configuration list was empty or not without having to add that condition check to all the sub classes :/

Comment: @George: again, a parent should have no knowledge of or dependence on its children. Perhaps you want to use a design pattern to facilitate your design.

Comment: I'm aware of this now, I just thought at compile time, the parent and child were just compiled as one. No biggie, I'll figure out an alternate way to handle this. Thanks